# JAVA API for cut fragment from mpeg-ts file

Tags: java, mpeg2-ts

I search a library that can cut fragment of mpeg-ts file. Now I use ffmpeg for this purpose but I'd like to leave it.

Now, I see on jcodec and mp4parser libraries but can't found needful API.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Java Media Framework is that what you're looking for. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html